# Not detecting motor port D

Tags: mindstorms, ev3, labview

We are trying to program in LabVIEW, using all 4 motor ports. On the port selector, port D is not even showing up.

Comment: Can you be more detailed in your question? What have you tried to do, what is LabVIEW telling you, what have you already researched on the Internet and how is your situation different than what you can find on Google and the likes?

Answer (score 2):

I think LabVIEW only works with 3 motors. You could use [EV3-G](http://www.lego.com/en-us/mindstorms/downloads/download-software) instead.